# OpenNebula: [HostPoolInfo] User couldn't be authenticated, aborting call

Tags: linux, authentication, opennebula

I installed OpenNebula 3.2.1 following the guide found under http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.2:ignc on a Debian 6.0.4 machine. Everything seemed fine until trying to execute the command

```
onevm list
```

Then I always get this:

```
oneadmin@opennebula-master:~$ onevm list
[VirtualMachinePoolInfo] User couldn't be authenticated, aborting call.
```

The file one_auth exists. I even gave the oneadmin user a password although it doesn't seem to be required according to the guide. I copied the password hash from /etc/shadow to the one_auth file. Still no success.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the answer from Peteris is a verbatim quote from the OpenNebula [documentation](http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.6:manage_users) which presumably is not clear enough...

Based on the question, 2 points seem to need clarification:

1. OpenNebula uses its own distinct authentication, NOT system auth, so the username and password in the file named in the $ONE_AUTH environment variable are ones set using OpenNebula itself.
2. The password field is not a hash, it is plaintext. For that reason it is important that you make sure the file has restrictive permissions, e.g. 600

Answer (score 1):

Needs to point to a file containing just a single line stating “username:password”. If ONE_AUTH is not defined, $HOME/.one/one_auth will be used instead. If no auth file is present, OpenNebula cannot work properly, as this is needed by the core, the CLI, and the cloud components as well.